# Does latest version of Aptana Studio 3 run on Yosemite with JDK 1.8?

Tags: java, osx-yosemite, aptana3

I just upgraded my Apple MacBook's OS to Yosemite (10.10.2) and afterwards I found out that my Aptana installation (ver.3.4.2.201308081805, according to the version.txt file of the root Aptana installation directory) does not run anymore:

> "To open AptanaStudio3 you need to install the legacy Java SE 6
>   runtime"

right after upgrading to Yosemite, I installed ver.1.8.0_31 of Java. So, I want to know whether installing the latest version of Aptana Studio 3 on Yosemite is going to resolve this since I do not want to revert to the legacy Java version of Apple.

Comment: shouldn't java be backwards compatible? What did Apple do there again :(

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation and browsing through several threads in this and other sites, I have concluded that this issue is not related to Apple. When it comes to JAVA on Mac OS X Yosemite, there are 2 options: either use Apple's Java implementation (found here: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) or use the latest version of Oracle's JDK (ver.1.8.0_31 as of posting this answer, found here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). It seems that Aptana Studio 3 is not yet compatible with Oracle's Java and requires Apple's Java in order to work properly.

PS: Important: the latest version of Oracle's JRE is NOT an option for Java on Yosemite.